# Looking for a program like php formater

Tags: php, text-editors

I got a php project which I have to develop but problem is last developer didn't care about readability of his work. So I ended up having hundreds of php files which are impossible to read. Look at this:
[image]

I found this website:http://beta.phpformatter.com/. 
I give this website php codes and it gives a clean and well-formatted php coeds to me. I'm looking for some kind of php editor that do this for me. 

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NetBeans for PHP](http://netbeans.org/) got an autoformatter which works quite well with PHP.

Select your whole code, and go to `Source` > `Format` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)

By the way you can customize it from the `Options` menu in order to fit your code convention (ident, brackets etc.)

[Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/) has a pretty good formatter (compatible PSR2).

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use this instead of `Notepad++`.

Comment: I prefer Netbeans because it support PHP 5.3 very well with auto completion on class, namespace etc. But if it fits your needs!